# Strange console output array and array.pop() in javascript function

Tags: javascript, arrays, console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Chrome's JavaScript console lazy about evaluating arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057440/is-chromes-javascript-console-lazy-about-evaluating-arrays)

I write next js function:

```
function popFromArray(arr){
    console.info(arr);
    console.info(arr.pop());
    console.info(arr);
}
```

When I write next code in console I expected next output:

```
>>> popFromArray([12, 432, 52, 523]);
[12, 432, 52, 523]
523
[12, 432, 52]
```

But I found strange behaviour for me (chrome and firefox):

```
>>> q = [12, 432, 52, 523];

>>> popFromArray(q);
[12, 432, 52, 523]
523
[12, 432, 52, 523]

>>> popFromArray(q);
[12, 432, 52]
523
[12, 432, 52]

>>> popFromArray(q);
[12, 432]
52
[12, 432]
```

Is anybody can explain why it happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to step over through the function code: it will report properly.

I think it's just a concurrency issue. Console output generation is done in parallel with program execution so result is unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

This is the intended behavior of `pop()`, according to the MDN `pop()` will:

> Removes the last element from an array and returns that element.

To realize your intention, you should try

```
function popFromArray(arr){
    console.info(arr);
    console.info(arr[arr.length -1]);
    console.info(arr);
}
```